# stunnel - how to replace the server certificate without interruption

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to understand the procedure to use for certificate replacement at expiration on stunnel. So I have a stunnel installation on Windows with a simple configuration:

```
[test1]
accept = 127.0.0.1:21234
connect = 127.0.0.1:21235
cert = p1.pem
```

The p1.pem file has the structure:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQD1f+2n88ThTvLn ....
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEFjCCAv6gAwIBAgIUHD/p+ctiyaWxZCd1LiFqC5vzKGQwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL ....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Using a java client application I could open successfully a SSL connection to the port 21234.

The p1.pem certificate is a self-signed certificate created using openssl. Before p1.pem certificate will expire we need to have a period where the server would accept two certificates (e.g. p1.pem and p2.pem).

I have tried concatenating the two files into p1p2.pem whith the structure:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
p1 key
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
p1 cert
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
p2 key
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
p2 cert
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

When I tried the same java client application it works with the public certificate of p1 but with the public certificate of p2 it returns:

```
Exception in thread "main"
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find v alid certification path to requested target at
sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source) at
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source) at
sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source) at
sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source) at
sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source) at
sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source) at
sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source) at
sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source) at
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source) at
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source) at
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source) at
sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source) at
java.io.OutputStream.write(Unknown Source) at clt.main(clt.java:16) Caused by:
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target at
sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source) at
sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source) at
sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source) at
sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source) at
sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source) at
sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source) ... 10 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
unable to find valid certification path to requested target at
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source) at
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source) at
java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source) ... 16 more
```

Comment: It would be better (more readable) if you copied your stracktrace with the correct linebreaks, and format it as 'code' (select then click the {} button, or put a line with 3 backticks before and after, or indent each line 4 spaces but that's more work) to retain those linebreaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR: you can't transition the server**

A TLS server, including stunnel, only uses one cert-and-key at a time, or optionally one per SNI (i.e. host domainname) *if* the client sends SNI, which browsers always do (since at least 2010) and *recent* versions of Java (IIRC somewhere mid-8 up) *usually* do but it may depend on how the code set up and opened the SSLSocket, which you don't show or describe. (To see get a net trace if possible (may not be for loopback/localhost if on Windows) or run the Java with sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl,handshake` and look.) This is because the client does not provide the server any information about which CA(s) or other cert(s) it 'wants'; in 1.2 and 1.3 it can specify the *signature algorithms* it will accept, but that usually does not distinguish between an older and newer cert.

stunnel in particular uses only the *first* privatekey in a `cert=` (or `key=` if specified) file, and while it can use multiple *chain* certs in a `cert=` file it uses only the first as the *entity* cert, both for a given 'service' and SNI. And your p2.cert presumably isn't a valid chain cert for p1.cert, so the stunnel config you posted always uses p1.key and p1.cert. If "... java client application ... with the public certificate of p2" means you put p2, but not p1, in the client's truststore, then of course that client doesn't validate a connection to a server that is using p1.

The *normal* method of renewing or otherwise transitioning (server) certs that is designed to work is to use CA-issued certs, under long-lived CAs, so that the server can be issued a new cert and the client will trust it because the CA continues to be valid and did not expire.

**If you must replace a selfsigned cert**, the only way that works with minimal interruption is:

1. configure the client or all the clients to accept *both* old and new certs (which may or may not involve bringing each client down momentarily, but multiple clients can be done at different times, especially if they are a pool or cluster or otherwise collectively provide a high-availability capability of some kind),
2. then change server from old to new (stunnel can reload without shutdown),
3. then optionally remove old from the client(s) (if necessary this can wait until their next downtime for other reasons, or even until the next cert replacement).

**But you may not need to.** Assuming you are using 'self-signed' with its correct meaning -- a cert signed with the *same key* it contains, not merely signed by you, and thus necessarily configured in the client truststore because there is no cert above it that can be used to verify it -- then **by my testing a default Java client** (that is, one that uses the default validator, as your code clearly does, and *doesn't* add any other validation outside, which we can't tell from here), then it **will accept** a self-signed cert in the truststore ***even after expiration***. (Oddly so, because the official API `CertPathValidator` *does* reject it. I'll try to look into this more later.) Set up a test machine (maybe a VM, so you don't risk corrupting any important files) and jump its date ahead, and see if it works, and you may avoid the whole issue.

Comment: Thank you for this! Indeed, it is a good solution to send the new public certificate to all the clients and make sure all of them have it and when we change the certificate on the server it will still work